# Constructing kernel matrix of subtractions between two vectors efficiently

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

Given X = ( x_1,...,x_m ), Y = ( y_1,...,y_n ), how to construct the m-by-n matrix K **efficiently** ? Without using a **for** loop ?
The (i, j) element of matrix K is 1/(x_i-y_ j).

A row-by-row construction is not efficient enough in my view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a 2D matrix with subtractions for each element of `Y` from each element of `X`. This can be done in a vectorized manner using **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** with `@minus` function handle to take care of the subtractions. Then divide `1` by each of those 2D matrix elements using `elementwise-division`. These two steps can be performed in one line to give us the desired output as shown below -

```
K = 1./bsxfun(@minus,X(:),Y(:).')
```

Comment: Is it better to combine these two steps, namely `K = bsxfun(@(x,y) 1/(x-y), X, Y')`?

Comment: No. It's 60% slower than your code. Used a slow Chromebook to check that.

Comment: @Yvon It's not because `@minus` is one of the in-built ones and as such I am guessing is an optimized version.